# remove free shipping method from custom shipping module magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping, custom-shipping-method

we want to remove **free shipping** method from custom shipping module **magento2**.

Any idea regarding above will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Haim - Do you have idea regarding the above mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `app/code/Magento/Shipping/Model/Carrier/AbstractCarrierOnline.php`

```
/**
* Calculate price considering free shipping and handling fee
 @param string $cost
 @param string $method 
 @return float|string
 @api
*/
public function getMethodPrice($cost, $method = '') {
    return $method == $this->getConfigData($this->_freeMethod)
    && $this->getConfigFlag('free_shipping_enable') 
    && $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal')
    <= $this->_rawRequest->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() ? '0.00' : $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($cost);
}
```

You can clearly see that there's a `configFlag` for `free_shipping_enable`

Comment: when the method is displayed through the custom shipping, for certain condition would like to remove the freeshipping method.

Comment: Now you're asking something else and totally unrelated. You want the shipping method to only be available under certain conditions?